# Should I define constraints on Jetbrain's Exposed, even though I don't use schema generation?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am developing with Jetbrains Exposed SQL framework

Considering I never use it's schema creation facilities and I use handmade sql scripts to generate/migrate database schema, is there any point on defining foreign key cascade behaviour, uniques and etc on the table object, or the framework only uses this options for schema generation?